# Comparison and stability.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

From my PDE textbook, it introduces that for $v,w\in C^{2,1}(Q_T)\cap C(\bar{Q}_T)$ be solution of,
$$
v_t-D\Delta{v}=f_1 \hspace{0.5cm}and\hspace{0.5cm}w_t-D\Delta{w}=f_2
$$
with $f_1,f_2$ bounded in $Q_T$. Then:

a) If $v\ge w$ on $\partial_pQ_T$ and $f_1\ge f_2$ in $Q_T$ then $v\ge w$ in all $Q_T$

b) The following stability estimate holds:$$
\max_{\bar{Q}_T}|v-w|\le\max_{\partial_pQ_T}|v-w|+T\sup_{\bar{Q}_T}|f_1-f_2|.
$$
It is a corollary given by the weak maximum principle. Though I understand the first conclusion, I can't understand the second. Particularly, how exactly to get $T\sup_{\bar{Q}_T}|f_1-f_2|$ in the inequality? And why the inequality is dealing with absolute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = v - w - C t$, where $C > 0$ is to be chosen. This satisfies
$$
z_t - D \Delta z = f_1 - f_2 - C,
$$
and if $C = \max_{\bar{Q}_T} f_1 - f_2$ the right-hand side is nonpositive. On the other hand, the constant function $y = \max_{\partial_p Q_T} v - w$ satisfies
$$
y_t - D \Delta y = 0.
$$
As $y \geq v - w \geq z$ on $\partial_p Q_T$, applying the maximum principle (part (a)) gives $y \geq z$ on $\bar{Q}_T$, so in particular
$$
v - w \leq C t + \max_{\partial Q_T} v - w \leq T \max_{\bar{Q}_T} f_1 - f_2 + \max_{\partial Q_T} v - w \leq T \max_{\bar{Q}_T} |f_1 - f_2| + \max_{\partial Q_T} |v - w|.
$$

Applying the argument in the reverse order, to $w - v$, would bound $v - w$ from below by the same quantity, giving the estimate in (b). But as you can see, that is really the combination of two one-sided estimates.